# How can I "stop" the graph which "hits the zero"?

Tags: maple

I have a simple model for the population:

```
a := 5; 
b := 1;
h := 25/4;, 
de := diff(P(t), t) = P(t)*(a-b*P(t))-h;
cond1 := P(0) = .5;
cond2 := P(0) = 2;
cond3 := P(0) = 5;
sol1 := dsolve({cond1, de}, P(t)); 
sol2 := dsolve({cond2, de}, P(t)); 
sol3 := dsolve({cond3, de}, P(t));
P1 := plot(rhs(sol1), t = 0 .. 5, color = blue);
P2 := plot(rhs(sol2), t = 0 .. 5, color = green);
P3 := plot(rhs(sol3), t = 0 .. 5, color = orange);
plots:-display(P1, P2, P3);
```

[image]

When the graph "hits the zero", population goes extinct, so I need to "stop" the graph there. I can use `Optimization[Minimize](...);` to minimize deviation from zero (and include this point, say, A, in `t=0..A`), but it's not always possible and kind of "brute-force". How can I "stop" the graph which "hits the zero"? Also, how can I find the point where non-extinct population becomes stable (say, 1% deviation from limit value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the differential equation, for an "exact" symbolic formula, without having to specify a particular numeric value for the initial condition.

```
restart;
a := 5:
b := 1:
h := 25/4:

de := diff(P(t), t) = P(t)*(a-b*P(t))-h:

solparexact := dsolve({P(0) = P0, de}, P(t));

                            10 P0 t + 4 P0 - 25 t
      solparexact := P(t) = ---------------------
                            2 (2 P0 t - 5 t + 2)
```

Let's pick off the right hand side, for convenience. This is P(t).

```
solparexact := rhs(solparexact);

                         10 P0 t + 4 P0 - 25 t
          solparexact := ---------------------
                         2 (2 P0 t - 5 t + 2)
```

We can solve that for a formula expressing where P(t) would become zero.

```
general_root := solve({t>0, solparexact}, t) assuming P0>0;

     general_root :=  / [ /         4 P0   \ ]           5 
                      | [{ t = - ---------- }]      P0 < - 
                      | [ \      10 P0 - 25/ ]           2 
                     <                                     
                      |                             5      
                      |           []                - <= P0
                      \                             2
```

That prints ugly in character-mode, and nicer in the Maple GUI. It is a piecewise, showing that there is no root when P0 > 5/2. That is, when the initial population is greater than 5/2 the population doesn't ever become zero.

We can evaluate that result at various values of P0. The following does that.

It is known as *two-argument eval*, to evaluate an expression for specific values (substituions) of one of more of its unknowns. This is a very useful bit of Maple syntax, which I'll utilize several times in all the code below.

```
eval(general_root, P0=2);

                      [ /    8\ ]
                      [{ t = - }]
                      [ \    5/ ]

eval(general_root, P0=0.5);

                  [{t = 0.1000000000}]

eval(general_root, P0=5); # no root

                           []
```

The closer P0 gets to 5/2, from above, the longer it takes for the population to ever get to zero.

```
eval(general_root, P0=5/2 - 1e-9);

               [ /                  8\ ]
               [{ t = 9.999999996 10  }]
               [ \                   / ]
```

We could even extract the formula (for the time t where the root occurs and the population becomes zero) within the piecewise, valid for P0>0 and P0<5/2,

```
genroot := eval(t, general_root[1]) assuming P0>0, P0<5/2;

                                4 P0   
                genroot := - ----------
                             10 P0 - 25
```

We can find the limiting value for the population, as t goes to infinity.

```
L := limit(solparexact, t=infinity);

                              5
                         L := -
                              2
```

We can re-express the exact formula for P(t) at particular values of P0.

```
S[3.0] := eval(solparexact, P0 = 3.0);

                          5.0 t + 12.0 
                S[3.0] := -------------
                          2 (1.0 t + 2)

S[5.0] := eval(solparexact, par = 5.0);

                      10 P0 t + 4 P0 - 25 t
            S[5.0] := ---------------------
                      2 (2 P0 t - 5 t + 2)
```

We can find the time at which the population gets close (relatively), to its limiting value. We can do that exactly, or in floating-point,

```
End[3.0] := fsolve( (S[3.0] - L)/L = 0.1, t = 0..infinity );

                End[3.0] := 2.000000000

solve( (eval(solparexact, P0 = 3) - L)/L = 1/10);

                           2
```

We can even find a general representation of that,

```
Endform := solve( {P0>0, t>0, ((solparexact - L)/L) = 1/10},
                  t) assuming P0>5/2;

    Endform :=  /                                11
                |         []               P0 <= --
                |                                4 
               <                                   
                | [ /    8 P0 - 22\ ]      11      
                | [{ t = --------- }]      -- < P0 
                \ [ \    2 P0 - 5 / ]       4
```

That too can be evaluated at particular values of the initial population size. These agree with what was found above.

```
eval(Endform, P0=3), eval(Endform, P0=3.0);

             [{t = 2}], [{t = 2.000000000}]
```

We could pick of the time value, alone,

```
eval(t, op(eval(Endform, P0=3.0)));

                      2.000000000
```

Or we could pick off the formula, under the appropriate assumption.

```
genend := eval(t,Endform[1]) assuming P0>11/4;

                            8 P0 - 22
                  genend := ---------
                            2 P0 - 5
```

And now for a plot, for a list of P0 values that attain zero population, and a list of values which do not.

```
Zerovals := [0.5, 1.5, 2.0, 2.1, 2.25, 2.3]:
P0vals := [3.0, 3.5, 5.0, 10.0]:

plots:-display(
  plots:-shadebetween(L, 1.1*L, t = 0 .. 4, linestyle=dot,
                      color=gray, transparency=0.5),
  seq( plot(eval(solparexact,P0=P0vals[i]),
            t = 0 .. eval(genend,P0=P0vals[i]),
            color=cat("Spring ",i), legend=P0vals[i]),
       i = nops(P0vals)..1, -1 ),
  plot(L, t = 0 .. 4, linestyle=dot, thickness = 3,
       legend=evalf[2](L)),
  seq( plot(eval(solparexact,P0=Zerovals[i]),
            t = 0 .. eval(genroot,P0=Zerovals[i]),
            color=ColorTools:-Color([1,1,1]-
                                    [i,i,i]/(nops(Zerovals)+1)),
            legend=Zerovals[i]),
       i = nops(Zerovals)..1, -1 ),
  axis[2]=[tickmarks=[op(Zerovals),L,op(P0vals)]],
  legendstyle=[location = right],
  size = [700, 500],
  view = [0 .. 4, 0 .. max(P0vals)]
);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Data are presented in the best possible way now.

Comment: I made a few edits: correct defns of `genroot` and `genend` as now used in `plot` call. Re-order legends by reordering plots. Add custom y-tickmarks to match `P0` and L values. Switch to brigher Datlon color palette. You can remove the legend entries, or the custom tickmarks, depending on which you prefer.

Comment: Thanks again, plot looks even better. Really useful ideas for plotting, I appreciate  depth of the information received.

Comment: This kind of problem can also be solved purely numerically using `dsolve(...numeric,events=[...])` where the event is the basic `halt`.  Or `DEtools[DEplot]` with the various values of the initial condition. A field-plot for the DE is also thus available. The symbolic solution above seems easier for this case, but a numeric apporach could cover a DE with no explicit, symbolic solution. See https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=dsolve/numeric/Events

Comment: That was a good tip about numeric approach since I've planned to analyze more complex models than this one (this was used as example because it's easy to predict what's going to happen with population from given DEs). It's great for me to know these details.